# Confusion about bash command vs. variable substitution

Tags: bash, command-substitution, variable-substitution

I've been writing one-line bash scripts on the command line since 1989.  These usually have the form:

```
for name in 1 2 3; do wc $name.txt; done
```

Now I'm trying to do some image manipulation with GIMP, using a script that takes two filenames for arguments.  Here's something that gives me a valid command line:

```
/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/MacOS/GIMP -b '(script-fu-overlay "png0004.tif" "png0000.tif") (script-fu-overlay "png0004.tif" "png0001.tif") (script-fu-overlay "png0004.tif" "png0002.tif") (script-fu-overlay "png0004.tif" "png0003.tif")'
```

It was generated with the help of a typical one-liner:

```
X=\'$(for name in 0 1 2 3; do echo \(script-fu-overlay \"png0004.tif\" \"png000$name.tif\"\) ; done)\'
```

But...and here is my question:

```
echo /Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/MacOS/GIMP -b $X
```

gives me the exact command line above, but when I run

```
/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/MacOS/GIMP -b $X
```

I get errors about not being able to open filenames that have quotes around them, but when I run

```
/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/MacOS/GIMP -b "$X"
```

everything works.  My real goal is to understand whether it's possible for me to write a one-liner without resorting to variables at all.  Something like:

```
/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/MacOS/GIMP -b \'$(for name in 0 1 2 3; do echo \(script-fu-overlay \"png0004.tif\" \"png000$name.tif\"\) ; done)\'
```

But that fails in apparently the same way that

/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/MacOS/GIMP -b $X

fails.

Comment: Change `png000$name.tif` to `png000${name}.tif`

Comment: This looks like a GIMP parsing issue, not a bash one. Try escaping the \ that surround your filenames: \\"png0004.tif\\"

Comment: You answered your own question: -b "$X" works -b $X doesn't. Hence the $(....) needs to be quoted as well for it to be treated as one single entity to -b option.

Comment: @Gohu may look like, but it's actually bash parsing, I'm quite sure. He composes a string that looks like the command line he wants to enter, but it will be treated differently, as quotes won't be evaluated at this stage.

Comment: @Gohu The `gimp` doesn't know. The shell removes the single quotes and passes the whole string between them as one parameter to `gimp`. `gimp` doesn't know how this parameter has been composed.

Comment: @Philippos Shell does not pass the the string between single quotes as one parameter. Since it is coming out command substitution, it shall be word split unless quoted by double quotes. Without which it shall appear to `gimp` as strange looking two parameters like 'file1.tif and file2.png'

Comment: @RakeshSharma My comment was on the meanwhile deleted second comment of Gohu, linking to some bogus discussion that "gimp doesn't like single quotes". And for `gimp -b 'no splitting here'` the string is passed as one parameter with the quotes removed. That's what Gohu didn't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it on the command line without resorting to shell variables.

```
/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/MacOS/GIMP -b "$(for name in 0 1 2 3; do echo \(script-fu-overlay \"png0004.tif\" \"png000$name.tif\"\) ; done)"
```

Note that we need to do away with the escaped single quotes since we are not doing an `eval` here. Only thing that is needed are the double quotes around the command expansion $(...) to prevent word split from happening PLUS pass the result as one single argument to `gimp`.

Answer (score 1):

`man bash` says:

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and pathname expansion [...]
>   After these expansions are performed, quote characters present in the original word are removed unless they have been quoted themselves (quote removal).

Thus, only quotes *from the original word* are removed. But those quotes of yours appear only after the expansion and they won't get removed.

In the given case, you can leave them away, as your file names don't need any quoting, but you'll run into problems with file names with whitespaces or other special characters. And neither quotes nor backslashes will help you as they are not considered to be quotes at this stage of processing.

**Edit to serve the "one step" request:**

But what if you have a bunch of files with whitespace like `foo file foo` and `bar file bar` and want to `cat` some of them?

Your command line would read

```
cat "foo file foo" "bar file bar"
```

but if there is more, you'll want to script it.

```
echo -n cat; for name in foo bar; do echo -n \ \"$name file $name\"; done
```

Will produce exactly the line you would enter, but

```
$(echo -n cat; for name in foo bar; do echo -n \ \"$name file $name\"; done)
```

will fail for the reason explained above. Enclosing everything in double quotes (as did help in your `gimp` case) will not work either, because the new command needs to be separated in words, but not within the quotes.

So what to do to make quoting work as if entered directly in the command line? Pass your string as command to the shell:

```
bash -c "$(echo -n cat; for name in foo bar; do echo -n \ \"$name file $name\"; done)"
```

That should be the most general approach for a one-liner executing a generated command.

Comment: Yes, but...should there not be a way to do this in one step?

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
$ /Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/MacOS/GIMP -b \
"$(printf '%s\n' '(script-fu-overlay "png0004.tif" "png'{0..0004}'.png")')"
```